# Rename Folders matching pattern using foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, rename

I'm building a simple Powershell script that recursively loops though a directory and removes the "My " prefix from specific folders but I can't seem to get this to work.
I can list the directories just fine but Rename-Item has no affect.

Any help would be grealy appreciated!

```
Clear-Host
pushd
$homeDrivesDir = 'E:\test\users'
$reportmode = $false

                foreach($homeFolder in (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $homeDrivesDir | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | Where-Object {($_.Name.contains("My Documents") -or $_.Name.contains("My Music") -or $_.Name.contains("My Pictures") -or $_.Name.contains("My Videos"))})){
                        if ($reportMode -eq $true) {
                            # reportmode is on, don't do anything
                            Write-Host "Directories To be Renamed" $homeFolder.Name -backgroundcolor red -foregroundcolor white
                        } else {
                            # reportmode is off, fix the permissions
                            Write-Host "Renaming Directories" $homeFolder.Name -foregroundcolor white -backgroundcolor red

                            try {
                                Write-Host $homeFolder
                                Rename-Item $_ -NewName $_.Name.Replace('My ', '')
                            } catch {

                            }
                        } #/if
                    } #/if
popd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write-Host is correctly outputting the folder name `$homeFolder`

You should use the same variable in your rename-item command instead of `$_`

```
Rename-Item $homeFolder -NewName $homeFolder.Name.Replace('My ', '')
```

However, this will only work if your current working directory is the same as the location of the folders you want to rename. Otherwise, use

```
Rename-Item $homeFolder.FullName -NewName $homeFolder.Name.Replace('My ', '')
```